# Image src doesn't look like it's going through asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm going through the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl.  In one of the chapters he is explaining about the asset pipeline, and that if I enter the link_to helper code with the image_tag like so:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails logo"), 'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
```

It should see produce something similar to this:

```
<img alt="Rails logo" src="/assets/rails-9308b8f92fea4c19a3a0d8385b494526.png" />
```

but in my browser I see the actual image directory

```
<a href="http://rubyonrails.org/"><img alt="Rails logo" src="/assets/rails.png" /></a>
```

Note the page renders fine in my browser, but I'm wondering why the code doesn't look like it does in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're probably viewing the page in the development environment. The hashed version of the image is created when the assets are compiled. This typically happens when you deploy your app to production.

Comment: Just to add some color to this answer, this is called "fingerprinting" and is explained in the [Rails Asset Pipeline documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).  There, you will see that you can control this behavior by setting `config.assets.digest` in your environment file (set to true to enable fingerprinting).

Comment: I wonder why in the book they don't mention this.  Is something new with the latest RoR version(s)?